# Calculate the result of combining three multivariate Gaussian distributions

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A Bayesian derivation of the Kalman Filter was provided by Ho and Lee (1964); this paper is available as a free pdf [here](http://www.dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc?AD=AD0604006). As part of their derivation, they substituted three multivariate Gaussian distributions for the three terms of Bayes' Theorem:

prior  $\propto$  (**x**$-$**u**$_x$)$^T$ **P$_0$**$^{-1}$ (**x**$-$**u**$_x$)

likelihood  $\propto$  (**z**$-$**H x**)$^T$ **R**$^{-1}$ (**z**$-$**H x**)

denominator  $\propto$  (**z**$-$**H u**$_x$)$^T$ (**H P**$_0$**H**$^T+$**R**)$^{-1}$ (**z**$-$**H u**$_x$)

where **z** $=$ **H x $+$ v**, **u$_x$** is the mean of **x**, **P$_0$** is the covariance of **x**, and **R** is the covariance of **v**.

The posterior distribution (also multivariate Gaussian) can be calculated using Bayes' Theorem as the product of the prior and the likelihood, divided by a normalising term (e.g. the 'denominator' term above). If we focus only on the terms inside the exponents of the Gaussian distributions, Bayes' Theorem can then be calculated (using the rules for products and divisors of exponential functions) as prior + likelihood - denominator, i.e. :

(**x**$-$**u**$_x$)$^T$ **P$_0$**$^{-1}$ (**x**$-$**u**$_x$)

$+$ (**z**$-$**H x**)$^T$ **R**$^{-1}$ (**z**$-$**H x**)

$-$ (**z**$-$**H u**$_x$)$^T$ (**H P**$_0$**H**$^T+$**R**)$^{-1}$ (**z**$-$**H u**$_x$)

Ho and Lee then state that, by completing the square, they calculate the posterior as:

(**x**$-$**w**)$^T$ **P**$^{-1}$ (**x**$-$**w**)

where **P**$^{-1}$ $=$ **P$_0$**$^{-1}$ + **H$^{T}$ R$^{-1}$ H**

**P** $=$ **P$_0$ $-$ P$_0$ H$^{T}$ (H P$_0$ H$^{T}$ $+$ R)$^{-1}$ H P$_0$**

and **w** $=$ **u$_x$** $+$ **P H$^{T}$ R$^{-1}$ (z$-$H u$_x$**)

I want to understand how to derive this result by completing the square. As part of my research on this problem, I have found proofs of the products of univariate and multivariate Gaussian distributions [(Bromiley 2014)](http://www.tina-vision.net/docs/memos/2003-003.pdf) as well as formulae to calculate the products of multivariate Gaussian distributions in the Matrix Cookbook (Petersen and Pedersen 2012; Section 8.1.8). Unfortunately, I have not found sufficient material to date to help me complete the square for this problem.

Can someone who is adept in manipulating multivariate Gaussian distributions please provide a proof of the solution for the posterior distribution derived by Ho and Lee?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what is Gaussian distributed ? a multivariate Gaussian distribution is $p( \|X\| < a) = \frac{1}{C}\int_{\|y\| \le a} e^{-(y-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (y-\mu)} dy$ with $\Sigma$ being self-adjoint and the normalization constant is $C = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-(y-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (y-\mu)} dy$, right ?

Comment: Here I have chosen to focus only on the terms inside of the exponential of each multivariate Gaussian distribution (i.e. each of the prior, likelihood and denominator terms). I want to ignore the calculation of the terms in the normalising constant of the posterior distribution.

Comment: To answer your question more specifically, the prior is Gaussian with mean = **u $_x$** and covariance = **P$_0$** $^{-1}$, the likelihood is Gaussian with mean= **H x** and covariance = **R** $^{-1}$ and the denominator is Gaussian with mean = **H u $_x$** and covariance = (**H P H $^{t}$ + R**) $^{-1}$. I hope that helps to clarify?